# Action item still appear after fragment replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, android-actionbar

I'm using navigation drawer - project frame from android studio 4+ - and I have two fragments in menu.

One fragment which contains android.support.v4.view.ViewPager. ViewPager contains two fragments, one of them has menu. When I use gesture to change fragment in viewpager menu shows and disappear depends on which fragment is visible now - everything is correct.

And now flow when something is wrong:

if I open first fragment from navigation drawer and swype to fragment with menu, and then change to second fragment using navigation drawer menu still appear - why? I cant understand.

EDIT:

if I add

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

and

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

to fragment which shouldn't has menu then problem is gone, but still I think root cause it somewhere else and above solution is dirty.

Answer (score 5):

I know that I am 2 years late to answer, however this may benefit programmers that face the same problem. I had the same issue and I solved it by simply calling

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

in *OnCreateView()*.

This will ensure that the new fragment has its own options menu which then can be created with *onCreateOptionsMenu()*. If you don't want to have any options menu just avoid implementing *onCreateOptionsMenu()*.